# How do I vertically align floated element?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, centering

What I need to achieve is to align `.btn p` vertically to the middle of `.btn img` height. Is that possible to make if the `.btn p` element is floated to the right? I need them to be on the same line, but when changed their displays to `display: inline block;` they are stacked vertically (and I don't know why).

I know that I could do it with `flexbox` really easily, but I need it to be supported by IE 9+ browsers, and `flexbox` is only [partially-supported by IE 11](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.slide1 {
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.slide1 h1 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4.75em;
}

.slider-btn {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 120px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.slider-btn a {
    display: inline-block;
}

.slider-btn p {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.5em;
    float: right;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> test </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="heading">
        <div class="slide1">
            <h1> Lorem Ipsum sit dolor amet </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-btn">
            <div class="btn">
                <a href="http://google.com">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/81x81" />
                    <p> Slide no. 1 </p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="btn">
                <a href="http://google.com">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/81x81" />
                    <p> Slide no. 2 </p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="btn">
                <a href="http://google.com">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/81x81" />
                    <p> Slide no. 3 </p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if the image size is fixed and known you can simply apply margin-top on the <p> tag and align it vertically with the image (unless if <p> height may change).

Comment: Unfortunetely it's not.

Comment: then you have another option. apply display: table; on the <a> tag and display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; on its childs.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

Changes: position, vertical-align, display and HTML

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slide1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.slide1 h1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 40px 0px;
}

.slider-btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;


  text-align: center;
}

.slider-btn a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.slider-btn p {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
   display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn a img{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section class="heading">
  <div class="slide1">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum sit dolor amet</h1>
     <div class="slider-btn">
    <div class="btn">
      <a href="http://google.com">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/81x81" /><p>Slide no. 1</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <a href="http://google.com">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/81x81" /><p>Slide no. 2</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <a href="http://google.com">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/81x81" /><p>Slide no. 3</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpup1yz2/4/)**